# Proof Involving Legendre Symbol and Quadratic Residue Multiplication

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues, legendre-symbol

I am struggling with this proof. I really cannot think of where to start:

Let $p$ be an odd prime, prove that:

$$\left(\frac{1 \cdot 2}{p}\right) + \left(\frac{2 \cdot 3}{p}\right) + \left(\frac{3 \cdot 4}{p}\right) + \cdots + \left(\frac{(p - 2) (p - 1)}{p}\right) = -1$$

If someone could just give me a push in the right direction, I am sure I could get it.

Comment: @Derik Hint: for any invertible $n$, $n(n+1)$ has the same quadratic character as $(n+1)/n = 1 + n^{-1}$.  What set of values does this range over for $n=1, \ldots, p-1$?

Comment: @ErickWong For example, $$(\frac{2 \cdot 3}{p})
 = (\frac{\frac{2 + 1}{2}}{p})$$ Is this what you are saying?

Comment: @Derik Yes, in the sense that you would interpret $\frac32$ as $3$ times the modular inverse of $2$.  That is  what I meant by "same quadratic character", that the Legendre symbols mod $p$ will be the same.

Comment: @ErickWong Hmm, how do we know that $$(\frac{2 \cdot 3}{p}) = (\frac{1 + 2^{-1}}{p})$$?

Comment: @Derik (Assuming you mean $3/2$ instead of $2/3$).  Just write it out carefully using $3 = 2+1$.  The distributive law holds modulo $p$ (indeed in any ring).  Unlike your earlier question on Euler's criterion, this problem is relatively challenging and requires some mastery of fundamentals to actually navigate the proof.

Comment: @ErickWong Well maybe I need a little more than a push. I am still confused with how we know that $$(\frac{n(n + 1)}{p}) = (\frac{1 + n^{-1}}{p})$$

Comment: @Derik, Oh, just multiply by $(n^{-1})^2$, which is always a square.