# Quadratic Reciprocity problem.. help!

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity, legendre-symbol

If $p$ is an odd prime, evaluate $\left(\frac{1\times2}{p}\right)+\left(\frac{2\times3}{p}\right)+\cdots+\left(\frac{(p-2)\times(p-1)}{p}\right)$

I don't know how I use properties of Legendre symbol. Please help!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: umm.. I tried ((p-2)(p-1)/p)=(1x2/p), and thought there is (p-1)/2 quadratic residue and quadratic nonresidue.. but it didn't help to evaluate that. I think the answer is -1.

Comment: Older posts about this: [$\left( \frac{1 \cdot 2}{p} \right) + \left( \frac{2 \cdot 3}{p} \right) + \cdots + \left( \frac{(p-2)(p-1)}{p} \right) = -1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/552521) and [Proof Involving Legendre Symbol and Quadratic Residue Multiplication](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1787905)
Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B(p-2)%5Ctimes(p-1)%7D%7Bp%7D%5Cright)%24&p=1).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$\left( \frac{1 \cdot 2}{p} \right) + \left( \frac{2 \cdot 3}{p} \right) + \cdots + \left( \frac{(p-2)(p-1)}{p} \right) = -1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552521/left-frac1-cdot-2p-right-left-frac2-cdot-3p-right-cdot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is
$$S=\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\left(\frac{k(k+1)}p\right)
=\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\left(\frac{k^*(k+1)}p\right)
=\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\left(\frac{k^*+1}p\right)$$
where $k^*$ denotes the modulo $p$ inverse of $k$.